# Como usar função WHERE em coluna criada a partir de uma consulta?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli, where

```
select a.campo1, b.campo1,replace(replace(b.campo1,'-',''),'.','') as resultado from dbo.tabela1 a, dbo.tabela2 b 
where a.campo1 = resultado
```

Eu estou tentando fazer o select acima, porém é exibido o erro "Mensagem 207, Nível 16, Estado 1, Linha 16: **Invalid column name 'resultado'**."

Como faço para transformar o "pedidos" em uma coluna válida?

Comment: E o que vem a ser "pedidos" já que tal nome não consta do comando que você postou?

Comment: Pedidos era o nome original do aliás resultante do replace, esqueci de editar essa parte. (E como é um selecta confidencial não posso manter os nomes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente o  seguinte

```
select a.campo1, b.campo1,replace(replace(b.campo1,'-',''),'.','') as resultado from dbo.tabela1 a, dbo.tabela2 b 
where a.campo1 = replace(replace(b.campo1,'-',''),'.','')
```

Não  da para  usar  um alias como  parâmetro

Comment: Mas não consigo usar o aliás como um "elemento fixo" nesse select ? Pq dependendo do resultado, eu precisaria usar o mesmo como parâmetro em futuros selects.

Comment: Cria uma view a faz o select na view pode charmar o campo do quizer    create view vxpto as select campo1 as resultado ...... / select * from vxpto where resultado=42 ....

Answer (score 0):

Tente:

```
WITH
    cte AS (SELECT campo1, replace(replace(campo1,'-',''),'.','') as resultado FROM dbo.tabela1)
SELECT cte.campo1, b.campo1, cte.resultado FROM dbo.tabela2 b 
WHERE b.campo1 = cte.resultado;
```